# Estimating output amplitudes of quantum circuits as GapP functions

Tags: quantum-gate, complexity-theory, probability

Let's fix a universal gate set comprising of a Hadamard gate and a Toffoli gate. Consider an $n$ qubit quantum circuit $U_{x}$, made up of gates from that universal set, applied to initial state $|0^{n} \rangle$.

The transition amplitude $\langle 0^{n}| U_x |0^{n} \rangle$ can be written as

\begin{equation}
\langle 0^{n}| U_x |0^{n} \rangle = \frac{f - g}{\sqrt{2^{h}}},
\end{equation}
where $h$ is the number of Hadamard gates and $f$ and $g$ are two #P functions. This equivalence is proven in https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0408129 (equation 6).

Let's say that we are given an efficient classical description of $U_x$ and we want to estimate this transition amplitude classically, upto inverse polynomial additive error. We do not care whether our estimated value preserves the sign of the original output amplitude.

A naive way to estimate the transition amplitude classically, given an efficient description of the circuit $U_{x}$ as the input, would be to estimate $f$ and $g$ individually, upto inverse polynomial additive error. Something like this is hinted in Section V of the paper linked.

But don't we need oracle access to the formulas corresponding to $f$ and $g$ (ie, two Boolean/3SAT formulas such that $f$ is the number of solutions for one, and $g$ is the number of solutions for the other) to individually estimate $f$ and $g$ respectively (upto an inverse polynomial additive error)?

Can we efficiently get a description of these two corresponding Boolean formulas just from the description of the quantum circuit $U_x$ given to us as input (and hence, not need oracle access to these formulas in the input)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a description of $ U_x $ you can efficiently find a decription of $ \textbf{B} $ and  $ \phi $ by iterating over the gates of $U_x$ and adding one "free" variable every time you have a Hadamard gate and imposing the constraint of the Toffoli gate.

Regarding the approximation, you can estime $f, g$ to additive error $ \frac{2^h}{\text{poly}(h)} $ (see [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/22387/approximating-p-hard-problems)) but this will give you $ \frac{2^{h/2 + 1}}{\text{poly}(h)} $ error for $|\langle 0^n|U_x|0^n \rangle | $.

In fact, you can't hope for a classical randomized poly-time algorithm to give an estimate of $|\langle 0^n|U_x|0^n \rangle | $ with additive inverse polynomial error unless BQP = BPP, since  if $ L \in$ BQP:

- $ x \in L \implies \text{Pr(aceptance)} > 1 - 2^{-n} \implies |\langle 0^n|U_x|0^n \rangle |^2 < 2^{-n} $
- $ x \notin L \implies \text{Pr(aceptance)} < 2^{-n} \implies |\langle 0^n|U_x|0^n \rangle |^2 > 1- 2^{-n} $

and with an estimate of $|\langle 0^n|U_x|0^n \rangle | $ with additive inverse polynomial error would allow us to distinguish between the two cases.

Answer (score 2):

I think there might be a confusion between a Boolean formula (which may be easy to evaluate) and the number of solutions or a difference in the number solutions of the Boolean formula (which may be very difficult to evaluate).  You're calling $f$ and $g$ #P-functions, but really you're interested in $\#(0)$ and $\#(1)$ which are *values* that count the number of solutions to a given function.

For example let $U_x$ be a quantum circuit; we can use this circuit to build a classical description of certain function, call it $\textbf B$.  We can let $\#(0)$ and $\#(1)$ count the number of positive and negative terms in the sum:

$$\langle \textbf b\vert U_x\vert \textbf a\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^h}}\sum_{x:\textbf B(x)=\textbf b}(-1)^{\phi(x)}.$$

That is, I believe that your classical description of $U_x$ indeed gives you sufficient information to get an efficient classical description of the formulae $\phi$ to which $\#(0)$ and $\#(1)$ count the number of $0$'s/$1$'s; however, that doesn't necessarily mean that you can efficiently evaluate $\#(0)$ and $\#(1)$ to a high-enough precision to calculate $\vert \#(0)-\#(1)\vert$.

There are some tricks such as [Stockmeyer approximation](https://rjlipton.wpcomstaging.com/2009/08/27/stockmeyers-approximate-counting-method/) that let you classically evaluate $\#(0)$ or $\#(1)$ *individually* to *some* precision, but these tricks are not efficient (being in Arthur-Merlin).  More importantly these tricks are nowhere near enough accuracy to efficiently evaluate the (absolute value of) the difference between $\#(0)$ and $\#(1)$.

Comment: This is where my confusion lies. Given an efficient classical description of $U_x$, can we, in classical polynomial time, find a description of the function $\textbf B$ and the formula $\phi$? If so, how? The paper outlines a method for it, but why is the method efficient?

Comment: I haven't studied the paper in a lot of detail but couldn't the method on FIG. 2 and equation 2 be generalized?  There are only a polynomial number of Hadamard gates $H$.

Comment: You're right. The method is efficient. A lingering question though: given a description for $U_x$, we can efficiently compute $\mathbf B$ and $\phi$. You remark it's not sufficient to "efficiently evaluate $\#(0)$ and $\#(1)$ to a high-enough precision to calculate $\vert \#(0)-\#(1)\vert$." But let's say we just want to compute it for some precision, like, let's say, inverse polynomial precision for some polynomial. Is even that not possible with known techniques?

Comment: If so, what is the bottleneck? Is it that even after getting an efficient description of $\textbf B$, it is hard to determine which $x$s satisfy $\mathbf{B}(x) = \mathbf{b}$? Would the problem (of efficiently evaluating the difference to inverse polynomial precision) have been possible to efficiently solve if the summation had been over all $x$s instead of only those $x$s for which $\mathbf{B}(x) = \mathbf{b}$?

Comment: I think the issue is that classically you might get some decent estimates of $\#(0)$ or $\#(1)$ up to "multiplicative" error using known techniques of universal hashing, but in order to get a reasonable estimate of the absolute value of the difference between $\#(0)$ or $\#(1)$ you'll need "additive" error.  I was able to follow much of Adam Bouland's lecture at the Israeli IAS [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8zn8YJ5hUH8) which touches on much of this.  (Someone in the audience had a throwaway comment that the classical techniques are akin to bitcoin mining).

Comment: Thanks for the link! It is informative. But I still don't seem to get what the bottleneck is for some inverse polynomial "additive" error approximation of the whole sum with the denominator (we don't care about the sign let's say) by approximating $\#(0)$ and $\#(1)$ individually to some additive error. Since we know an efficient description for $\phi$, can't we just directly apply the technique mentioned in Case 2 of the accepted answer here (https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/22387/approximating-p-hard-problems)?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think the problem is most interesting when $\#(0)$ and $\#(1)$ are close to each other initially.  For example you can consider a Monte-Carlo alg. to separately evaluate the volume of two polytopes centered at the origin that are of similar size and of similar shape and of a similar orientation, but the Monte-Carlo algorithm would likely fail to evaluate the volume of the symmetric difference if the two polytopes look really close to each other.  I think in the linked question one of $\#(0)$ or $\#(1)$ would already be large and hence trivial to solve.

Comment: Indeed, the problem is that Stockmeyer gives you an approximation up to a multiplicative accuracy, but multiplicative accuracies don't behave nicely under differences.

Comment: So, in summary, inverse polynomial multiplicative error estimation of the whole sum by inverse polynomial multiplicative error estimation of $\#(0)$ and $\#(1)$ individually is hard, because multiplicative accuracies aren't preserved under differences, but inverse polynomial additive error estimation of the whole sum by inverse polynomial additive error approximation of $\#(0)$ and $\#(1)$ individually is possible, but it may not preserve the sign if $\#(0)$ and $\#(1)$ are close to each other. Is that correct?

Comment: That sounds close to correct but multiplicative error to find any one of #0 or #1 individually might still require inverting a hash function which can be tough, in NP.